# Update column from another join column ,,

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

First it should be easy for the DB'es but its really giving me pain here i dont know why ,,

I have two tables , [Table1] named Applicationforms and [Table2] named WFInstance
i need to update the FormSubmitDate in Table1 with the startedDate value in table 2 
where the FormSubmitDate is null. 
I write the following query

```
UPDATE    ApplicationForm
SET              FormSubmitDate = wfi.StartDate
FROM         ApplicationForm app ,
                      WorkFlowInstances wfi

WHERE     app.FormSubmitDate is null and wfi.applicationID = app.ID
```

when i run the query the SQL regenerate the query to this one,,

```
UPDATE    ApplicationForm
SET              FormSubmitDate = wfi.StartDate
FROM         ApplicationForm AS app INNER JOIN
                      WorkFlowInstances AS wfi ON app.ID = wfi.ApplicationID CROSS JOIN
                      ApplicationForm
WHERE     (app.FormSubmitDate IS NULL)
```

I tried to write another statment using join ,,

```
UPDATE ApplicationForm
SET FormSubmitDate = wfi.StartDate
FROM ApplicationForm 
JOIN WorkFlowInstances wfi ON ApplicationForm.ID = wfi.ApplicationID 
WHERE  FormSubmitDate is null
```

and the SQL generate the same new syntax,,

now when i run the code , [all records] formSubmitDate fields filled with the first value of second table startDate. even if i have one record contains null value in table1

What i am missing here !?

Comment: does my suggestion help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does what you want. Try it and let us know.

```
UPDATE tabl3
SET formsubmitdate=(SELECT startdate
  FROM table4
  WHERE table4.id=tabl3.id AND tabl3.formsubmitdate is null);
```

Another way to write the same thing would be

```
UPDATE tabl3
SET formsubmitdate= startdate
FROM table4 where tabl3.id = table4.id and formsubmitdate is null
```

Comment: finally ,, the second query is worked ,, can i ask you why you set from table 4 , since we need to update in table 3 ?! 
i was trying the same query but with [ from table 3],,,
I am not very good in DB , but as fare as i know that the join returns the mach record right ?!

Comment: It is startdate from table4 that's why it works. The join returns all the rows that satisfy the on condition. What I have written is different conceptually to the join.